# need a double function on a click

Tags: jquery, include, scrollto

please I am not a expert developer and I need a help on this function; I write from Italy, sorry for my english.

I have my page.html with this function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
// select all the links with class="art", when one of them is clicked, get its "href" value
// load the content from that URL and place it into the tag with id="contentart"
$('a.art').click(function() {
var url = $(this).attr('href');
$('#contentart').load(url);
return false;
});
});
</script>
```

in the html code I have a lot of

```
<a class="art" href="part1.html">link 1</a>
<a class="art" href="part2.html">link 2</a>
<a class="art" href="part3.html">link 3</a>
ecc. ecc
```

and at end the container:

```
<div style="width: 100%" id="contentart"></div>
```

My problem is that when the customer makes click on the link href, the div opens at very long distance (2 or 3 screen bottom) because ther're meny links and the customer does not see it. 
The question: is possible a function that include the page in the "contentart" and makes a scrollTo until the top of this DIV "contentart"?
Much thanks from Italy.
Arcibald

Comment: Thanks very much to all, the function is perfect, its works, but the links don't work and I have a new request; please, see later.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#contentart").offset().top
}, 2000);
```

See [jQuery scroll to element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035/jquery-scroll-to-element)

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I had added animated scroll to your div

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    // select all the links with class="art", when one of them is clicked, get its "href" value
    // load the content from that URL and place it into the tag with id="contentart"
    $('a.art').click(function() {
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#contentart').load(url);

        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: parseInt($('#contentart').offset().top)}, 'slow');
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to quickly scroll to a location within the same page is to

> use an anchor with an id inside it

**Example:**

```
<body>

<p><a href="#foo">Go to foo</a></p>

<h2>alpha</h2>
<p>alpha alpha</p>

<h2>beta</h2>
<p>beta beta</p>

<h2><a id="foo">Chapter 4</a></h2>
<p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p>

<h2>gamma</h2>
<p>gamma gamma</p>
```

futher reading [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp)